# How to not show PORT from Nodejs API Requests

Tags: node.js, apache

I was working in a project and sudden noticed that while react is calling node api, i can see port number also in console network, which i think is not secure.

So is there any tool, settings whcih we can use to hide ports from api calls.

I am using apache as server, node api and react frontend.

Thanks

Tried virtual host settings but not worked

Comment: Why would you think it's "not secure" to show the port? It really doesn't matter if it's secure or not, knowing the port is necessary for the application, because otherwise how would you connect to the server?

Comment: If no port is provided every request will be directed to port 80, but it's not more secure